# Pumping Lemma Applied to 3 Variables

Tags: finite-automata, pumping-lemma

Prove That the Language

$L_1 = \{0^i1^j0^k | i < j\ or\ i > k\}$

is not regular using the pumping lemma.

I am not sure how to begin with this I ended up using the string:

$0^p1^{p+1}0^{p+1}$

S = 00001111100000

It holds for the conditions because the first set of 0s is less than the set of 1s, and the last set of zeros doesn't matter because I only have to meet one condition

I Divided the string as follows, {000,0,1111100000}

in the case:
$xy^2z$ = 000001111100000 is not part of the language because i = j = k so neither condition is met. Please tell me if I did this right and give me some pointers because I have not found a single source that shows how to deal with 3 variables with an or statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand a bit how the Pumping lemma works.
You're not free to choose the value of $p$ or how to divide the string, but need to show that there's *no* factorization for some $w \in L$ with $|w| \geq p$ and $p$ arbitrary that would satisfy the pumping lemma.

The trick here is to find values of $i, j, k$ such that after pumping $j \leq i \leq k$.
We know that the pumped substring $y$ must have length $1 \leq |y| \leq p$ for the pumping length $p$, and can use this to clamp the value of $i$ between sufficient $j, k$.

Assume $w = 0^p1^{p + 1}0^{2p} \in L$ such that $|w| \geq p$ for the pumping length $p \geq 1$.
Then, if $L$ was regular, there must be $w = xyz$ with

1. $|y| \geq 1$,
2. $|xy| \leq p$, and
3. $xy^iz \in L$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Now we must use *only* 1.-3. to derive a contradiction.
Notice that from 2. it follows that $y \in 0^+$, and

$$xy^2z = 0^{p + |y|}1^{p + 1}0^{2p}.$$

But then by 1. it follows that $p + |y| \geq p + 1$ and by 2. that $p + |y| \leq p + |xy| \leq 2p$.
Therefore $xy^2z \notin L$ contradicting 3. ⭍

Comment: Hmm, that makes much more sense. Thank you.